# ASP.NET Redirect and End Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, webforms

So I read up a lot about how to properly use Response.Redirect without causing some errors.

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);

Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Situation:  A user logs in the site and visits a page that lists forms.  The user sits on that page for an hour doing nothing (which would log them out).  The user clicks a button to edit a title (which requires a postback).  This results in the user object being null since it logged him out of the session.

What I have done: In the page load, check if the user object is null and if it is, redirect to the login page.  That is what should happen right?

Problem:  The button event is STILL firing.  Is it because I have the following line of code?

```
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

How can I stop the event from being firing when I simply want to redirect to the login page?

I know I can provide true in the redirect code, but that will cause an error too right?

```
Response.Redirect(url, true);
```

What I currently do (which is not the best way I know):  In the button event, I again check to see if the user object is null.  If it is not null, proceed with the code to edit the title (recording who edited it).  This is a bad way of handling this.

What I have seen:  Wrap all events with Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected.  But if I have several pages and lots of button events, this can get a bit annoying.  Is this the only way to handle this situation?

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Account account = Session["Account"] as Account;
    if (account == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?NewSession=true", false);
        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        return;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Account account = Session["Account"] as Account;
    Label1.Text = account.userID.ToString();
}
```

Again, if I am already on the page, and the session expired, and I click Button1, the Button1_Click method is still being called.  What I provided will give me a "NullReferenceException".  Page_Load IS being called, and it is making the redirect.  However, Button1_Click is still being called even with the return statement in Page_Load.

Thanks!

Comment: try 'return;' right after Response.Redirect()

Comment: @ZohaibAslam That will end the Page_Load method, but the click event method will still be called after that right?

Comment: no. because you send a request of redirect so that event will not be called. try this. i hope it will work

Comment: @ZohaibAslam It did not work, it still fired the event.  I will add the example code on my initial post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about `Response.Redirect(url, true)`. It is kind of expensive because it throws `ThreadAbortException` causing the current thread to terminate which is not what you want most of the times.

> There is even a KB exists on this topic [KB312629](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629).

And yes, with your code it is not possible to prevent events from firing for the current `IHttpHandler` (which `Page` class implements) using built-in classes/methods.

So I would suggest to create base page class and add a `bool` field indicating about request completion request plus method that will call `ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` and will set the flag to `true`. Also you'll need to override [`RaisePostBackevent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.raisepostbackevent(v=vs.110).aspx) method to take control over controls (not Page) events invocation on page.

```
public abstract class BasePage : Page 
{
    private bool shouldNotRaiseEvents;

    protected void CompleteRequest() 
    {
        shouldNotRaiseEvents = true;
        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }

    protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, string eventArgument)
    {
        if (shouldNotRaiseEvents) 
        {
            return;
        }
        base.RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl, eventArgument);
    } 
}
```

Your updated code would be:

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);
CompleteRequest();
```

Also please note that if you have something inside `LoadComplete`, `PreRender`, `SaveViewState`, `Render`, `Unload` event handlers and you don't want this code to execute after redirect call you'll need to override that methods also.

Comment: Oh that is great!  So if I override the RaisePostBackEvent, it will cancel all postbacks if I should not raise events?

Comment: @Ethosik yes, if you don't need to raise events on controls like `Click`, `TextChanged`, etc. you don't call `base.RaisePostBackEvent` otherwise you need to call the base method.